# Is there any role that can't be changed by Heart of Fenrir?

Tags: werewolv.es

My question concerns any role that is in extended games.

To mind comes: Neutral roles (Drunk/GR). I also wonder if Players that are night immune becuase of role and/or items make an exception as well.

Answer (score 1):

This was tested recently, at the moment even night immune roles can be changed into an Omegawolf. But this may be due to change, since it caused quite weird effects when we tested converting a Vampire into an Omegawolf.

So this answer might be wrong in the near future!

Comment: thanks! I'm going to hold off on marking this as answer just because I'd like to have the solution that is chosen sometime soon here! :)